# How to save state of Visual Studio C++ debugging session?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio C++ 2013. I am running a number cruncher program so it proceeds linearly/predictably. However I have a test which takes several hours to run, before asserting due to logic error in my code. I can get a breakpoint before the crash, but I can't step backwards without starting all over again.

Is there any way to get Visual Studio to save the state of my program, so that I can restart at that point again?

The program state is very complicated and it would take a lot of work for me to save all the state to files myself for resuming later.

Comment: You mean like a crash/memory dump?

Comment: @EdChum I mean I can "save" at the breakpoint, and "reload" to the breakpoint later, as if I never went forward. Any method to do that will help!

Comment: AFAIK no, I've never encountered a method to save a debugging session or rollback a session state

Comment: i also don't know a method to "save" any states, but if it takes several hours to crash, maybe it is a memory leak or an access volatile. did you tried to run it with valgrind?

Comment: @user1810087 Probably is not due to memory leak. It's not really crash, an assert triggered due to logic error.

Comment: Do you access any container multithreaded without mutexing? And i also agree with jakubs answer.

Comment: @user1810087 No. Although there are multiple threads only one is active at a time. It's actually SystemC project.

Comment: checkout [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/177344/VSDebugHelper-Capture-memory-snapshot-of-a-debugge), maybe it helps.

Answer (score 7):

When debugging in Visual Studio (even from a breakpoint) use Debug|Save Dump As... to save the current debugging state.  When saving, make sure you select "Minidump With Heap" so you have access to heap memory.

Later you can double click the .dmp file to open it with Visual Studio right where you were.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, stepping through code does not appear to be supported from dumps.

Answer (score 6):

You may consider virtual computers. You can make their snapshots and save them. This may be an overkill, but is guaranteed to work.

Comment: I agree with Jakub. There are many advantages to virtual computers, and this particular method of saving state is one I employ often.

Comment: So this is not like system restore on windows correct? We can take snapshot with running sofware included ?

Comment: @Mathai : worked for me some time ago. VS 2015. Of course if the program you are debugging must not depend on timing too heavily. In my experience a debugging session and running program survive even a windows hibernate/restore cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this is to save your meaningful state variables together as an object and then write it out to JSON.  Then add a unit test that takes an input JSON file, deserialises (converts it back into an object) and then call your method.

For instance, imagine you have this type that your method takes (which is your meaningful state)

```
public class MyInputType
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string StudentMajor { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say that's the input param to your `SlowMovingClass`, that looks like this:

```
using System;

public class SlowMovingClass
{
    public void SlowMethod(MyInputType input)
    {
       
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + input.ID);
        Console.WriteLine("CreatedDate: " + input.CreatedDate);
        Console.WriteLine("firstName: " + input.firstName);
        Console.WriteLine("lastName: " + input.lastName);
        Console.WriteLine("StudentMajor: " + input.StudentMajor);

    }
}
```

We can modify your class to, for instance, read an environmental variable to see if the `ShouldLog` value is set to true.

If so, then we can convert the input value for this.method to JSON.

```
//add this line to SlowmovingClass
 bool shouldLogJson = bool.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ShouldLogJson") ?? "false");
```

Then add this line to the body of the method to convert and write to JSON.

```
 if (shouldLogJson)
        {
                var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(cache);
                var path = @"c:\temp\debugCache.json";
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, json);
        }
```

With all that done, you can now just write a unit test to take this cache value and call your method.  Then you skip everything else about the slow object state population process and can jump right back into the guys of the problem.

This has saved me *a lot of time* over the years.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSlowMethod()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\input.json");
        MyInputType input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyInputType>(json);

        SlowMovingClass slowMovingClass = new SlowMovingClass();
        slowMovingClass.SlowMethod(input);
    }
```