# In Python, is there any way to save/dump/serialize a PDB debugging session?

Tags: python, debugging, serialization, dump, pdb

I've been working with Python programs which take several hours to complete, but crash occasionally. To debug, so far I have been adding conditional breakpoints, which drop me into a PDB session whenever a problem occurs. This is great because pinpointing the exact cause of the problem is hard, and the interactive session lets me explore the whole program (including all the stack frames and so on).

The only issue is, if I ever accidentally close or crash my debugging session, I need to start the whole program again! Reaching my breakpoint takes several hours! I would **really**, **really** like a way of serializing a PDB session and re-opening it multiple times. Does anything like this exist? I have looked into dill to serialize an interpreter session, unfortunately several of my types fail to serialize (it also isn't robust to code changes down the line). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified your operating system of choice, but in linux world there is a criu utility - https://criu.org/Main_Page  , which can be used to save an application state. Now there are a lot of pitfalls, especially with tty-based applications (see https://criu.org/Advanced_usage#Shell_jobs_C.2FR) but here is an exaple.

1. I got a simple python application with pdb debug point, let's call it `app.py`:

   ```py
   print("hello")
   import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
   print("world")
   ```
2. After running this application with `python app.py` you get expected

   ```
   hello
   > /home/user/app.py(3)<module>()
   -> print("world")
   ```
3. Get your pid with `pgrep -f app.py`, in my case it was 17060
4. Create a folder to dump your process

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/criu
   ```
5. Dump your process with

   ```
   sudo criu dump -D /tmp/criu -t 17060 --shell-job
   ```

   notice that you current process will be killed (AFAIK due to --shell-job key, see link above).
   you'll see

   ```
   (Pdb) [1]    17060 killed     python app.py
   ```

   in your tty
6. Restore your process with

   ```
   sudo criu restore -D /tmp/criu --shell-job
   ```

   your tty will be restored in a same window where you used this command.
7. Since debugger is attached, you may type `c` and enter to see if it actually worked. Here's the result on my machine:

   ```
   (Pdb) c
   world
   ```

Hope that helps, there are a lot of pitfalls that might make this approach unfeasible for you.

The other way is to run your code in a VM and snapshot disk and memory each time. It might not be the best solution resource-wise, but many hypervisors have a nice UI, or even shell utilities to control state of virtual machines. Snapshoting tech is mature in any hypervisor now days, you shouldn't run into any problems. Setup remote debugging and connect with your favorite IDE after bringing your snapshot back.

Edit: There is also an easy way to do this if you are running your applications in containers and you OS supports podman and criu 3.11+

https://criu.org/Podman

You can use something like

```
podman run -d --name your_container_name your_image
```

To snapshot use

```
podman container checkpoint your_container_id
```

To restore use

```
podman container restore your_container_id
```

All these commands require root priviliges. Unfortunately i wasn't able to test it because my distro provides criu 3.8, and for podman 3.11 is required.

Same functionality is available as experimental flag in Docker, see https://criu.org/Docker

Comment: This is a very interesting answer! I'll look into this tomorrow. Although, I would have loved a portable solution (I work on both Mac & Linux). Your solution is very general, so I guess that's the price to pay. I'm quite surprised there doesn't seem to exist anything like a resumable core dump; in general I really don't need to checkpoint any process at any time (although being able to do that is super cool).

Comment: I guess VM is the best "portable" solution, you may look into Vagrant to automate provisioning of your development VM. As of "resumable core dump" - criu is exactly this, basically a coredump. I looked at C# and Java related questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992590/how-to-save-state-of-visual-studio-c-debugging-session or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115417/does-eclipse-debugger-support-save-restore-or-checkpoint-rewind/12120723#12120723 - both have their drawbacks. Maybe IDE developers are not really interested in this functionality when virtual machines exist.